# What is the inverse of numpy's log1p()?

Tags: python, numpy

I transformed my data with:

```
Y = np.log1p(Y)
```

What is the formula to transform the values back to the natural values?

```
back  = np.e**Y
```

This did not work.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.expm1()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.expm1.html#numpy.expm1) which is the inverse of [`numpy.log1p()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.log1p.html)

```
import numpy as np
Y = np.log1p(Y)
back = np.expm1(Y)
```

Answer (score 6):

`Y = np.log1p(X)` just calculates `Y = log(1+X)`

It follows that to reverse this you would do

`X = np.e**Y - 1`